# accessing url segments in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to know that is there any way to get uri segment like codeigniter provide..
In codeigniter we can do ;

```
$this->uri->segment(3);
```

to get 3rd segment of url..
Let say i have an url like;

```
www.example.com/param1/param2/param3/param4
```

How can i get parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up a solution like zend router regex setting ;

```
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
                'module/(.*)',
                 array(
                        'module' => 'module',
                        'controller' => 'index',
                        'action'     => 'index'));

    $router->addRoute('module', $route);
```

in module index controller's index action ;

```
    $paramArr = explode("/",$this->_request->getParam(1));
```

Comment: Seems along way to go for simple an operation. Urls in ZF are always (unless you change it) Key value pairs. So if you know the url you know the parameters. www.example.com/key/value/key/value

Answer (score 1):

Well in the default route setup in a zend framework app you would have:
modulee:/controller:/action/param:/value:/param2:/param2

So for:

```
/admin/news/edit/id/12/name/newstest


echo $this->getParam('id'); // prints 12
echo $this->getParam('name'); // prints newstest
```

Pretty sure:

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

Should work too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: but what if i dont have a key like id, it's just a value of params?

Comment: @tylerdurden I'd have to check tocumentation but if you set a route so that the first param is id then you should be able to get to it thru $_GET['id'] regardless of if you see the word ID in the parameter. You could also, i guess, explode the url to get to the params.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams(); //Retrieves all parameters sent
$this->getRequest()->getPost(); //Retrieves the post array
$form->getValues(); //retrieves form values
```

These are common ways to work with the request object, they are not

this is what to expect from `$this->getRequest()->getParams();`
Notice that the url parameters are **module, controller, action, station = 1, submit = Submit**

```
Params array(5) {
  ["module"] => string(5) "admin"
  ["controller"] => string(5) "index"
  ["action"] => string(5) "index"
  ["station"] => string(1) "1"
  ["submit"] => string(6) "Submit"
}
```

This is the same request using `$this->getRequest()->getPost();`

```
Post array(2) {
  ["station"] => string(1) "1"
  ["submit"] => string(6) "Submit"
}
```

to get these values on your own use Zend_Debug::dump($var, 'label');
Created with Zend Framework.

This `echo $_GET['id'];` is considered very bad practice in ZF.

Comment: it's not working because after the controller first param was expected to be a action with a view.. But currently it was a just dynamic value without view and absoulutely it's not action so I get a "page not found" error.